# Unable to serve static files in a Django development environment with Pinax

Tags: python, html, css, django, pinax

I'm trying to customize the Pinax theme that comes with starter projects. For some reason, I can't get my external css stylesheet to load. In the terminal, I get this error when I try to load the page that should be loading custom css:

```
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
   url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"),        name="home"),
url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
       document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is what I think is relevant in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use
a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/",
  "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
]

 # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
 # various locations.
 STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: [18/Mar/2016 13:26:06] "GET /site_media/static/css/stylesheet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a little time to figure out where I was supposed to put a custom stylesheet. The settings.py file indicates:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
]
```

In my case (since the PROJECT_ROOT directory is named "mysite") that translates to:

```
mysite/static/dist/css/stylesheet.css
```

If you try putting your stylesheet there (or the same spot relative to your PROJECT_ROOT). It *should* work.